# Get-Content command not recognized

Tags: powershell, logstash

We have script which is normally executed within a unix environment.
The following is a line from the script:

```
command => 'use/bin/tail -n 1 %{path} | grep --silent -F "%{message}" && rm -f {path}'
```

When run within PowerShell, the `use/bin/tail` path is obviously not recognized. As an alternative I tried this:

```
command => 'Get-Content -n 1 %{path} -Tail | grep --silent -F "%{message}" && rm -f {path}'
```

However, while `Get-Content` is recognized when run from the PowerShell command line itself, it is not recognized when run from within the script.
This is the error message:

> 'Get-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What is the correct way to replicate the unix `tail` command when running a script in PowerShell?

Answer (score 8):

The error you receive:

```
%1 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

is a standard error from `cmd.exe`, not `powershell.exe`:

[image]

Your command is not getting executed by a powershell host, but by a regular command prompt - PowerShell would have mentioned the possibility of invoking a "cmdlet, function, script file or operable program" in case of "command not found" (misspelled Get-Content on purpose to demonstrate):

[image]

You'll also need to edit the command a little more, for PowerShell to make sense of it, the first statement in the pipeline would be:

```
Get-Content $Path -Tail 1
```

assuming that `$Path` contains the path to the file you're tailing.

Comment: Thanks. The script is being run from the Powershell command line - what needs to be done so it is executed by the powershell host, not the command prompt?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of that? I find that pretty hard to believe?!

Comment: @user1052610  Not sure about the last part. Are you waiting for a certain message to occur and then deleting the file once that happens?

Comment: I cannot paste a screenshop from the machine I am on, but this is the command within the Powershell window : " C:\logstash\bin> .\logstash agent -f logstash.conf"

Comment: The idea is to tail to get the last row, process all the rows, and after a row matching the last row is processed, to delete the file

Comment: I don't see a `Get-Content` in the line `.\logstash agent -f logstash.conf`.

Comment: logstash.conf is a script file which contains the line "command => 'Get-Content - ...". the 'command' keyword makes a call to the OS.

Comment: Seems like logstash on Windows defaults `command` execution to `cmd.exe` for compatibility. We can't solve your logstash issues, sorry

Comment: Thanks. That works, and it recognizes Get-Content. But it throws up on 'sls' or 'Select-String'